# PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer - Can it load all files from given directory path?

Tags: java, spring

Does the Spring PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer take a directory location and load all properties file, without me having to specify the file names explicitly.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"> 
        <property name="location" value="<path to all properties files>" />     
</bean>
```

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:file1.properties,classpath*:project-common.properties,classpath*:project-${spring.profiles.active}.properties"/>
```

In my case, it was a legacy system so property files didn't have some standard names but for sure you can use wildcards to reference your property files.

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:*.properties"/>
```